# find the number of tuples of positive integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

find the number of tuples (a,b,c,d) of positive integers

\begin{array}{l}
{a^3} = {b^2}\\
{c^3} = {d^2}\\
c - a = 64
\end{array}

answer should be one of

0 , 1 , 2 , 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$b^2,d^2$ are squares, so $a^3,c^3$ are squares, so $a,c$ are squares. The only positive squares with difference 64 are $17^2-15^2$ and $10^2-6^2$. So there are just two solutions for $(a,c)=(36,100),(225,289)$. It is easy to see that in each case there is one solution for $(b,d)$. So the total number of solutions is 2.

Comment: how did you figure out those squares with difference of 64 and how to know there are no more of them

Comment: @user347954 $$x^2-y^2=64 \Rightarrow (x-y)(x+y)=64$$ There are only few ways of writing 64 as the product of two integers ;)

Comment: Well, there are lots of ways of doing that. For example, you have $h^2-k^2=64$, so $(h+k)(h-k)=64$. Now just check a few cases (the only pairs of factors with product 64 are (1,64),(2,32),(4,16),(8,8). The first and last are obviously ruled out.